# Solution this problem then I opened android stodiu

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio-3.0, dart-async

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.2.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> assert pluginDirectory.exists()
> |               |
> |               false
> \root\snap\flutter\common\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\aucamera_android 0.9.8+3\android

- Try:

I opened  app it is ready

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.